# Show that $f \equiv 0$

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $$\int_0^1 f(tx) \,dx=0, \forall t\in \mathbb{R}$$
Show that $f \equiv 0$.
$$$$
$\int_0^1 f(tx) \, dx=0$

$u=tx \Rightarrow du=t \, dx$
$x=0 \rightarrow u=0, x=1 \rightarrow u=t$

So $\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f(u) \, du=0 \Rightarrow \int_0^t f(u) \, du=0$
$$$$
Could I show that $f \equiv 0$ using the above relation?

Comment: You can show $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0$ for all $a$, $b$. This will easily imply your result.

Comment: @DavidMitra Using that $$\int_0^t{f(u)}du=0, \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$??

Comment: I edited in order to change f(x)dx to f(x)\,dx$ (in particular, $t\,dx$ definitely looks better than $tdx$), and I noticed that you're enclosing every function being integrated in {curly braces}, thus: \int_0^1{f(tx)}dx.  Is there a reason for doing that?

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, there is no particular reason...Is it wrong to write it in this way??

Comment: Yes. $\int_0^b f-\int_0^a f=\int_a^b f$.

Comment: Just wondering about $f(x)=(x-0.5)$, the integral results in zero in the specified interval but f is not identical to zero.

Comment: @EmmadKareem not just ∫f(x)dx=0, but ∫f(tx)dx=0,for every real number t

Comment: @MaryStar : We frequently see absurd over-use of curly braces here --- things like { {{{\int}}} { {{\cos}}{{x}^{{2}}} } }, that makes editing harder.  And I wonder where it's coming from.  Is it all just use of absurd software found on the web somewhere, or are there also people who feel a need to do it that way?

Comment: @Seth, thanks for your explanation, but $f(x)= t(x-0.5)$ would still give the same zero result. What am I missing?

Comment: @EmmadKareem $f(tx)\neq tf(x)$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I thought that I had to enclose the integrated function in curly braces...I didn't know that it is better without them... Thanks for noticing it!

Comment: @Seth, thanks again, however, in this case it still won't make a difference, never mind, I was just curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that you have shown $F(t)=\int_0^t f(u)\,du=0$ for all $t$. So, because of the fundamental theorem of calculus $0=F(t)=\int_0^t f(u)\,du$ is differentiable and $F'(t)=f(t)=0$ $\forall t.$ That is, $f\equiv 0.$

Comment: I got it!!! Thanks a lot for your answer!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the transformation $x\mapsto t^{-1}x$, we get for $t>0$
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(tx)\;dx=\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\;dx=0.$$

Since $t$ is arbitrary and $t^{-1}\neq0$, we find $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\;dx=0$ for every $a>0$.  This implies that $f\equiv0$ on $[0,\infty)$, as $f$ is assumed continuous (I assume you know how to prove this part).

To get $f\equiv0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ just take $t<0$ and use the fact that $\int_{0}^{-a}f(x)\;dx=-\int_{-a}^{0}f(x)\;dx$ for all $a>0.$

Comment: I understand!!! Thank you very much!!!